# Trouble with SQL query execution using JDBC. getting error with result set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, web-scraping, jdbc

Im doing a webscaping project in Java and im having trouble with executing the SQL code to load the variables. im using IntelliJ with maven as the build.

I keep getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1135)
    at com.cst3511.website.scraper.Scarper.main(Scarper.java:54)
```

this is my code for the scraper class

```
public class Scarper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

        final String url =
                "https://www.myshiptracking.com/ports-arrivals-departures/?mmsi=&pid=GB&type=0&time=&pp=50";

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Element table = doc.select(".cs-table").first();
            Elements rows = doc.select("div.table-row");


            for (Element row : rows) {

                String event = row.select("div.col:nth-of-type(2)").text();
                String time = row.select("div.col:nth-of-type(3)").text();
                String port = row.select("div.col:nth-of-type(4)").text();
                String vessel = row.select(".td_vesseltype.col").text();

            // connecting to SQL
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oceana",
                        "user", "pass");
ResultSet rs;

                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO status_table(status, time, port , vessel) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                stmt.setString(1, event);
                stmt.setString(2, time);
                stmt.setString(3, port);
                stmt.setString(4, vessel);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+""+ rs.getString(2)+" "+ rs.getString(3)+""+ rs.getString(4));
                }

            
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in my error it says line 54 which is

```
 rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

I just dont know what im missing here...
Appreciate any Geniuses out there to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeQuery()` is meant for fetch (`SELECT`) statements that return results.

`INSERT` (as well as `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) statements should use `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: Thanks friend you're amazing